# Replacing rims with a 3mm effective diameter difference - can spokes be reused?

Tags: wheels, spokes, wheel-building

I'm planning to change the rims from 27.5 (ERD=566mm) to 27.5+ (ERD=563mm). Will I be able to reuse the spokes in this case, or is it worth getting new ones?

Comment: It may depend on whether your spokes were originally cut on the long or short side, how much thread they have, and whether you're willing to shorten them yourself if they have enough threads left.

Comment: My general advice is that unless you have a *very* good reason, reusing spokes isn't a good idea -- for the cost, putting in new spokes+nipples is a much safer and easier bet. A counterpoint is [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/reusing-spokes.html).

Comment: Yikes, it's hard to argue with Guru Jobst when it comes to wheels.... To mix metaphors, that's like arguing with the Pope about the Trinity.

Answer (score 5):

It is completely normal to replace a worn out rim by transferring the existing spokes to a new rim - it's slightly easier than relacing the wheel, since you can tape the rims together and transfer each spoke one by one (slacken off the tension on all the spokes of the old wheel before you start!). A 3mm difference in ERD will correspond to about 1mm in ideal spoke length - unless the existing spokes were too long (ideal is top of spoke at bottom of screwdriver slot) this shouldn't be a problem. Washers under the nipple heads (eg Sapim polyax) would help compensate if the spokes are on the long side. Going the other way (smaller to larger ERD) too-short spokes can be compensated for with longer nipples - although for a 1mm difference I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Longer nipples will help if the OP was transitioning in the other direction (i.e., the spokes were being effective shortened), but here the spokes will be effectively lengthened meaning the spoke will protrude out the back of the nipple toward the tube, meaning less spoke threads will be engaged on the nipple regardless of how long the nipple is.